# What methods can I use to aid in modeling a smaller data set when I have a significantly larger data set with fewer variables?

Tags: modeling, predictive-models, missing-data, small-sample

I currently have a data set with about 4,000 rows.  The current model I have established for it is not very good, and I am going to receive more data for about 150 of these points, and I'm hoping that there will be a very high correlation between the new variables and the response variable.

Normally I would opt to use imputation or data removal, but it is very wasteful to throw out 95% of the data, especially when parameter estimates can still be useful, and imputing that large of a portion of a data set seems like bad practice.  My goal is to build a predictive model (most likely just a linear regression) using the variables.  Is there any way I can use the majority of the data set to aid in this modeling?

Edit: I am using cross-validation and mean-squared error to measure predictive capability, since I am not using time series data.

Comment: well one thing is you will want to plot your data. With the new 150 data points, if you find something to be a good predictor, do a scatter plot of the response vs. each other predictor with each data point shaded/colored based on the good predictor.

Comment: Of course I'm looking at various relationships between variables, but at this stage I'm looking for methods that can utilize the several thousand data points that do not have all variables present.

Comment: What I mean is you look at those 150 data points to see if there is a within group relationship. For example say you had data on height and weight of humans and then you added gender for 50 data points. You could then plot weight vs. height with gender color coded. This would help you potentially infer the gender in the remaining thousand data points. At a minimum it would give you some intuition as to what to do next.

Comment: My current issue is this (as far as modeling goes):

Say that I want to use cross-validation with mean-squared error to determine predictive capabilities.  If I use several thousand data points to predict a few hundred, I can expect better results on average than if I use 120 points to predict 30 (for 5-fold cross validation).  Adding new variables to the model can improve its quality despite the decrease in sample size.  My question is how I can use the data from the old model to enhance the new model.

Comment: This isn't my field, but this seems like pertinent info to include in the main body of the question so others can better help you. It isn't clear from your question that you intend on using cross validation. (I will delete this comment once you have made the appropriate edits) I think I misunderstood the question.